# Socket.io not listening to two connections simultaneously Python

Tags: python, sockets, flask, socket.io-1.0

Below is the python script written on socket.io. I have data continuously emitted from server to the web browser. However, the client can have emit 'closeSSH' in between and the event 'nodeID' should be stopped. Can someone help me to make socket.io listen to multiple events at the same time?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
# Import 'Flask' libraries for web socket programming with the client/web-browser
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
from flask.ext.socketio import SocketIO, emit
import flask
import pxssh
from socket import *
import socket
from flask.ext.cors import CORS, cross_origin
import time

# INITIALIZATIONS
noOfNodes = 48
# Initialize all the TCP sockets
tcpClientSockets = dict()
for i in range(48):
    tcpClientSockets[i] = socket.socket()

tcpPort = 5000
bufferSizeRecPacket = 102400
nodeIPAddress = '192.168.1.'
startNode = 11
endNode = 58

# Class which provides the web socket communication with the Client/Web-browser
class CORNET_3D_WebSocketConnection:
    # Configure the Flask server
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'secret!'

    # Change the configuration such that requests from external IP addresses are accepted
    cors = CORS(app, resources={r"/foo": {"origins": "*"}})
    app.config['CORS_HEADERS'] = 'Content-Type'
    app.debug = True

    socketio = SocketIO(app)
    def __init__(self):
        # Server to run on port 8888
        self.socketio.run(self.app, host = '0.0.0.0', port=8888)

    @app.route('/', methods=['GET','POST','OPTIONS'])
    @cross_origin(origin='*',headers=['Content-Type','Authorization'])
    def index():
        # TODO: Get the node status for all the nodes
        return ''

    @socketio.on('nodeID')
    def startSpectrum(initParams):
        # TODO: Add the client to the list of clients
        # TODO: SSH to the node specified
        current_client_id = request.environ['REMOTE_ADDR']
        print current_client_id
        # Extract the transParams
        transParams = initParams['transParams']
        nodeID = initParams['nodeID']

        # Get the IPv4 address for the node
        nodeIPv4Address = nodeIPAddress + str(nodeID)

        # Validate the IPv4 Address
        try:
            validate = CORNET_3D_ValidateParameters()
            if validate.isIPv4AddressValid(nodeIPv4Address):
                # If parameters are valid in the IPv4 address
                if validate.isParamsValid(transParams):
                    try:
                        # TODO: Add the client IP address to the list of connected clients
                        time.sleep(1)
                        tcpClientSockets[nodeID - startNode].close()
                        spectrumParams = "PARAMS--f:" + str(transParams['f']) + " b:" + str(transParams['b']) + " n:" + str(transParams['n']) + " r:" + str(transParams['r'])
                        print spectrumParams
                        try:
                            print 'Connecting'
                            print nodeIPv4Address
                            tcpClientSockets[nodeID - startNode] = socket.socket()
                            print 'Create Tcp client sockets'
                            tcpClientSockets[nodeID - startNode].connect((nodeIPv4Address, tcpPort))
                            print 'Connected'
                            tcpClientSockets[nodeID - startNode].send(spectrumParams)
                            print 'Sent spectrum data'
                            while True:
                                spectrumData = tcpClientSockets[nodeID - startNode].recv(bufferSizeRecPacket)
                                tcpClientSockets[nodeID - startNode].send('spectrum..........................................')
                                emit('time', spectrumData)
                        except Exception as e:
                            print "Exception caused in TCP connection -- Start spectrum. Error: ", e
                        except Exception as e:
                            print "Exception caused in Validate -- Start spectrum. Error: ", e
                else:
                    emit('error', 'Invalid parameters for the node')
            else:
                emit('error','Invalid IP address for the node')
        except Exception as e:
            print "Exception caused in Start Spectrum. Error: ", e

    @socketio.on('getMetrics')
    def getMetrics(message):
        # TODO: Get metrics to be implemented
        print 'Get metrics'

    @socketio.on('closeSSH')
    def closeSSH(nodeID):
        # TODO: Remove the client from the list of connected clients
        try:
            print 'CLOSE SSH'
            #tcpClientSockets[int(nodeID) - startNode].send('exit..............................................')
            print 'Exit sent'
            tcpClientSockets[int(nodeID) - startNode].shutdown(socket.SHUT_RDWR)
        except Exception as e:
            print "Exception caused in Closing the connection with the client. Error: ", e

    @socketio.on('disconnect')
    def disconnect(nodeID):
        # TODO: Remove the client from the list of connected clients
        try:
            print 'DISCONNECT'
            tcpClientSockets[int(nodeID) - startNode].send('exit..............................................')
            tcpClientSockets[nodeID - startNode].close()
        except Exception as e:
            print "Exception caused in Closing the connection with the client. Error: ", e

    @socketio.on('users_req')
    def getClientsConnected():
        # TODO: Get the clients that are connected to the web socket through web browsers
        print 'Users Req'

# Class which validates parameters and IPv4 address
class CORNET_3D_ValidateParameters:
    def isIPv4AddressValid(self, ipAddress):
        try:
            socket.inet_pton(socket.AF_INET, ipAddress)
        except AttributeError:
            try:
                    socket.inet_aton(ipAddress)
            except socket.error:
                    return False
            return ipAddress.count == 3
        except socket.error:
            return False
        return True

    def isParamsValid(self, parameters):
        try:
                f = int(parameters['f'])
                b = int(parameters['b'])
                n = int(parameters['n'])
                r = int(parameters['r'])
                return True
        except ValueError:
                return False

if __name__ == '__main__':
    webServer = CORNET_3D_WebSocketConnection()
```

Comment: If you are using gevent or eventlet for your server, you need to monkey patch the standard library, to ensure that all I/O calls are routed through the green thread enabled libraries.